# Finding every possible value of $n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all integers $n$ such that $|2n^3 -6n^2 +4n+3|$ is a prime.

Comment: have you tried anything? what is your idea? could you find an upper bound ?

Comment: Prove that every value is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using N.S factorization, you get :

$2(n)(n-1)(n-2)+3$, Notice that $n,n-1,n-2$ are consecutive numbers.

If you choose any $n >2$, one of the  $n,n-1,n-2$  is multiple of three.

Therefore, solution is just $(n=2,1,0)$

Comment: $n=0$ is a solution too.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $x^3-3x^2+2x=x(x-1)(x-2)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 3\!:\,\ f(n)\, \equiv\, n-n^3 \equiv\ 0\:$